# Windows doesn't boot after updating to 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, windows

Windows 7 still appears as an option in grub but when i choose it, it does nothing and goes back to the grub selection screen. I have tried boot-repair but it's still the same issue. Here's the log from boot-repair : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6468928/ .

Answer (score 6):

- Boot `windows installation disk` then select the `windows repair` or `repair your computer` option before you go into the installation process.
- After selecting windows repair option,it will take you to the next screen.In that screen select the `command prompt` option
- Then run the below commands,on it.

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr
  bootrec /fixboot
  bootrec /rebuildbcd
  ```
- This will overwrite the grub installed in windows partition.
- Atlast boot [`boot-repair-disk`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and click on the `recommended repair` option.Now it works.