# Unable to boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, windows-7, boot-repair

after installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS i was unable to boot Windows 7 nor its Recovery partition
They both appear in the boot menu but they dont manage to work.

I've tried using boot-repair without success. here is the output of it -

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6470381/

Comment: what error comes while you try to boot windows7?

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/381601/windows-doesnt-boot-after-updating-to-13-10/381603#381603

Comment: on line 1088 says **Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda3**

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common problem, so don't worry. You are not alone, in fact, I was once in the same boat. There is also a very simple fix to your problem. Here's what you can do:

1. Boot into Ubuntu.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in to open Terminal.
3. Type `sudo update-grub` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Reboot when done.

----MORE INFO----

While `boot-repair` does run `update-grub`, there are some cases where it actually breaks things. For reasons unknown, I find that I can fix these by running `update-grub` from the actual Ubuntu installation. I don't know why this is, but the solution works, so you can't complain. Anyway, good luck with your install, and I'm sorry you are having trouble so early on.

Comment: **Incorrect**, as Boot-Repair has already done `update-grub` (see line 1082 of Xeus log). Dillmo, please could you indicate cases where typing the update-grub command fixes a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Which menu item are you using. You have the version of os-prober that still creates BIOS boot chain load entries that do not work with UEFI. The bug has been fixed only in the very newest 13.10 with updates.

grub2's os-prober creates wrong style (BIOS) chain boot entry

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1024383

Boot-Repair also has done the rename for "buggy" UEFI which often is not needed. I would undo that.

With the renamed file you cannot directly boot Windows from UEFI menu as it really is shim.

To undo & to rename files to their original names, you just need to tick the "Restore EFI backups" option of Boot-Repair.