# How to restore Windows 7 loader

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue

I have this situation: I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop. Then decided to install Ubuntu 12.10 alongside it. The installation was successful and I'm able to have a dual boot, Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

After sometime I decided to delete Ubuntu from my laptop so that I can use the space that was used by Ubuntu. I deleted the partition used by Ubuntu using the disk management of windows.

After restarting the laptop, Grub rescue appear and Windows 7 is not loading anymore. Trying to fix my problem, I decided to use the Linux live-USB with Ubuntu 12.10 on it. After the installation the loader screen appear, the Ubuntu and Windows 7 is already there. Trying to boot on Windows 7 by selecting it on the selection, error appears saying that the windows is not able to load due to some software changes.

What will I do to retrieve the windows and all the files on that partition? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: its because grub boot-loader is affected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/381601/windows-doesnt-boot-after-updating-to-13-10/381603#381603

Answer (score 1):

Here are the ways [to fix your Windows XP/Vista/7/8 bootloader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader):

### Using Windows installation disc:

- Boot with your Windows Vista/7/8 installation DVD or USB (read: [how to make a Windows bootable USB](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Bootable-Windows-7-or-Vista-USB-Drive)),
- Choose your regional settings, select your Location/Keyboard setting then click *next*,
- Click on *Repair your computer*,
- Choose the correct installation of Windows from the operating system list box and then click *next*,
- Then in the *System Recovery Options* screen choose *Command Prompt*,
- From there, type in the following 2 commands:

  `bootrec /fixboot`

  `bootrec /fixmbr`

Now close the two windows and click "Restart." Take out your Windows DVD and hopefully, you will be left with your Windows bootloader.

### Using [Boor-Repair disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/):

In **Advanced options** of the **[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)** disc, choose to *Restore MBR* under the *Main options*. Next under *MBR options* select the Windows 7 partition for *Partition booted by the MBR* option. Then click the *Apply* button.

Comment: I try this step: booting on Windows 7 installation DVD but it's not working. It seems it's not booting on CD/DVD drive of my laptop. 

I tried creating USB startup disk using the Windows 7 DVD as the source and boot in USB and it seems the same problem occurs. It's not working. What can I do now? I badly needed to restore my Windows 7 OS. Thanks!

Comment: Check your BIOS settings. If it's configured to boot with CD/DVD/USBs then you might have to check your Windows DVD.

Comment: For steps to change the boot order so that you're able to boot with CD/DVD/removableDevices, visit: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm or http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Bios-to-Boot-from-a-CD-ROM and then you can resume your Windows 7 rescue operation.

Comment: I already set the boot sequence to CD/DVD as the primary but it has exclamation mark " ! " before the name of the CD/DVD drive. I think that's the reason why it's not booting on that drive. Then I tried using the boot repair OS Uninstaller but still it's not booting to windows. Here's the link generated by boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6502120/ hoping for any solution from genuises like you guys. Thanks a lot for patienly answering my questions.

Comment: Since you've deleted the Ubuntu partition, GURB's configuration files got deleted as well and hence the error. As you are able to boot with USB flash drives, you could try creating a Windows 7 bootable USB drive and fix your MBR (updated answer contains the link). Or you can give a try windows MBR recovery tools provide by Hirens Boot CD, Super Grub Disk among others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot from windows installation dvd and choose recovery. Then in command prompt type:

```
fixmbr
```

Answer (score 0):

**On MBR style disks and BIOS booting:**

Any tool or method which can write a Windows MBR.

(does not need "bootrec /fixboot" as stated in this case)

---

**On GPT disks and UEFI booting:**

Just reorder NVRAM boot entries - put Windows first (can be done in firmware)

and/or delete Ubuntu boot entry.