# Bootloader prevents windows login

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I tried Ubuntu and tried to get updated graphics installed, but none of them took. They were always met with a message stating that their generic 390.xx for my Nvidia would be fine, so I left it alone.

When I went to restart and go back into Ubuntu, it loaded with a crappy 800x600 resolution, so I navigated to the devices to change that, but there were no other options. I was getting fed up fast, since I wasn't all that familiar with Ubuntu anyway and fixing it would be something for another time, maybe even another "ME". So restarted again, went into windows, went to disk manager, deleted the Ubuntu partition, made it free space, then expanded the drive back to normal size.

I was pretty sure such a move wouldn't take without another reboot, so I did. Then the bootloader kicks in and tells me I have an invalid OS, entering recovery mode...

So here I am now with no way to get back into windows and Ubuntu's default to crash at the door in the bootloader isn't helping. It would be nice that SHOULD it be missing something, it defaults to the OS that DOES work, such as Windows 10. That's my dilemma. Any fixes out there?

Thanks in advance for any and all help I can get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822708/restore-windows-bootloader)

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot with Windows in live USB mode. Then go to repair **This PC > Command Prompt**.

Try to recreate MBR using the following link

https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/amp/