# GRUB menu always appears on boot despite not dual-booting

Tags: boot, grub2, drive

I run a fully Windows computer with Kubuntu installed on an external drive. Even when the drive isn’t plugged in, the Grub command terminal appears on boot and I have to type `exit` to stop it.

It’s just an inconvenience, but is there any way to make the menu simply not appear whenever the drive isn’t plugged in? I’m not technically dual-booting so I don’t know why the menu appears in the first place.

Comment: Welcome, it's because when you installed Ubuntu, the bootloader GRUB was installed in your *internal* drive, not in the *external* (In the process of installation you can choose where to intall it). So you have to reinstall the windoes bootloader.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/831905/931617) for example, but you can find many more. If your machine is EFI configured, it could be more complicated.

Comment: Thank you!! (Idk how to reply to comments yet)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Grub Customizer

```
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Run, then:

General settings -> Show menu (uncheck)