# "Error: invalid signature" on Windows after attempting to delete Ubuntu partition and GRUB - how can I restore Windows' boot loader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Can anyone help me access Windows again?

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu running on my machine, with GRUB as the bootloader. I wanted to disable GRUB and remove my Linux partition. Following some online tutorial, I restarted Windows in Command Prompt mode. As a result of what I did there, GRUB doesn't recognise the Windows partition any more and throws an "invalid signature" error. Ubuntu still loads with no issue.

Any clue what's happening? How can I get back to using Windows?

Please consider that

1. My objective is still to remove GRUB and Ubuntu, so restoring the Windows bootloader would be enough for me
2. I'm probably not as techy as most Linux users... please keep it simple! :)

Thanks a lot for any tip!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore Windows 7 loader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383808/how-to-restore-windows-7-loader) and [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a windows installation disk and use it to restore the windows boot loader. You should choose to repair system option. Then, start command prompt. and type the following commands:
`c:\`

`bootrec /fixmbr`

`bootrec /fixboot`

`bootrec /scanos`

`bootrec /rebuildbcd`

The third command may ask you if you want to add the entries, you should select yes. This should rebuild the windows boot loader. Then turn off the computer. go to firmware settings (BIOS settings), put windows boot manager above grub.

Then start your pc and go to windows from windows boot manager. Now, follow the following steps:

- Press `Win+R` keys
- Type `diskmgmt.msc` and press enter.
- Identify your linux partition from the disk management utility and delete that partition.
- Now open command prompt with administrative privileges and enter the following commands
- `mountvol s: /S`
- `s:`
- `cd EFI`
- `rmdir \S ubuntu`

This will delete the ubuntu folder from ESP(EFI System Partition). Now restart your computer to verify that the ubuntu entry is gone from windows boot manager.

If the entry is still there o you get stuck at some point, comment below I will be happy to help. If the answer helps you then mark it as solution and upvote it please.