# Not Getting OS Selection menu after Boot-Repair

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

I had Ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed on my laptop with `/home` partition of about 246GB (and all other partitions like `/` and `/boot` etc. with variable sizes).
I shrinked the drive and made a new one of 100GB from `/home` and installed windows 8 there. After that Grub menu was not being shown as obvious.

Then I booted live cd (same Ubuntu 12.04) and did "recommended repair" by boot-repair. It said everything went fine but when I start the system, Grub does not show the option to select windows OS.

Only those, with Linux-generic and recovery kind of options, but not Windows Loader.

Here is the log file from [boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6529537/).

Comment: upload gparted screenshot to imgur.com and post the link here.

Comment: You need to repair your windows bootloader.Try this,it should really help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/381601/windows-doesnt-boot-after-updating-to-13-10/381603#381603

Comment: Isn't that what has happened here? I installed windows and it worked fine so that means it had already overwritten the grub. Then I booted into live cd and repair it.

Comment: but you say in the question that Grub does not show the option to select windows OS.plz tell what's your actual problem is.

Comment: My actual problem is this only that the grub does not show the OS selection menu. But isn't it that the steps you just said have already been implemented in the process I've done till now?

Comment: btw here is the gparted screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/2navfW7.png?1

Comment: did you run `sudo update-grub` command

Comment: When? While executing "recommended repair"?

Comment: boot into ubuntu os.open up the terminal and run `sudo update-grub` command.

Comment: Just did. But no gain.

Comment: in that gparted screenshot where is your windows partition.

Comment: let us continue the discussion here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company

Comment: I can't talk there as I don't have 20 reps. Windows partition is the one of ~100GB NTFS file system.

Comment: I'm here only waiting for your answer (and others' as well).

Comment: is my answer help you.

Comment: I've just added something which may help a bit more to understand the problem.

Comment: Windows only boots from primary partitions, so grub need to find the boot files in sda2. But your sda2 has these /menu.lst /grldr /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /grldr. The menu.lst is from grub legacy and /grldr is grub4dos. Best to remove those and just leave the two Windows boot files bootmgr & BCD. Then os-prober may have a chance to find it with a sudo update-grub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- From the screenshot,it was clearly shown that you installed Windows on a **logical partition**.Windows doesn't boot from a logical partition,it only boots from a primary partition.
- So delete `/dev/sda8` and install windows on a primary partition other than extended partition.
- For this,follow the below steps.

  1. Boot ubuntu-live-disk(so that your ubuntu partition will be unmounted and you will be able to resize it) and install gparted by running the below commands on terminal,

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted
     ```
  2. Right click on the `/dev/sda8` ntfs partition and delete it by selecting delete option.
  3. Now the unallocated spaces before and after `/dev/sda8` combine into one.(unallocated space= 3.74 MB+100.09 GB+4.74MB).
  4. Then you have to move the total unallocated space,just below to the `/dev/sda7` linux-swap partition,so that the total unallocated space will be throw out of the extended partition.For this,
  5. Right click on the `dev/sda6` and select **Resize/Move** option.Click on the slider and move it to the left atmost.
  6. Now the unallocated space comes just below to the `/dev/sda6`.

     [image]
  7. Try the same like i did on *step 5* to move the unallocated space just below to the `/dev/sda7` linux swap partition.
  8. Now the total unallocated space of about 100 GB are comes at the last of the extended partition.Now right-click on the extended partition and click on the Resize/Move option then you can be able to shrink or shorten the extended partition to throw 100 GB unallocated space out of the extended partition.
  9. Right click on the unallocated space just below to the extended partition and select New option.
  10. From that create a new *primary ntfs* partition.And then install Windows os on it.

Comment: How do I make a primary partition? I can only shrink the /home partition (sda7) which I did. How to make it primary?
edit: Windows did load (over writing grub) but later I used boot-repair to get it dual booted.

Comment: After searching, I got to know that sda1-sda4 are primary partitions. But I don't think there is any way to get the new partition to be any of those sda1-sda4. 

Can you tell if there is some? Thanks

Comment: Thank You very much. I will surely try the way how you brought the logical partition out of extended but I still have some doubts, which if you could solve, will be very much appreciated.

But I can't use the chat here. If you can give any other contact info, that will be great. For the time being, I've repaired Windows and using it only.

Comment: you can post as comments here.After that don't forget to delete that.

Comment: I cannot upvote since I lack the min number of reps:

Alright, 1. If windows can boot only from primary partition, how is it able to boot when only windows is used (as I am using currently replacing grub by windows boot manager)?

Comment: 2. When I see the partitioning in windows computer management, it shows all of them as 'Primary'. Why is that so?

Comment: 3. Is it sure that if I delete the sd8 and then following your method, brings a partition out of extended, to make it primary, there won't be any problem using those /boot and /recovery partitions? What I've understood is that system contains the data about where the boot sectors etc (I may be wrong here) are situated and all that info, with the name (number) of partition would be situated in the tables it forms. But as we'll change the partitioning, there will be difference in the name and/or sectors etc. which may lead to malfunctioning from using those partitions.

Comment: In only windows os pc's ,windows must be installed in primary partition otherwise it won't.I didn't see partitions in disk-management.But by using gparted,it was easy to understand.All partitions inside the extended partition must be logical partition.

Comment: Here's what I see in disk management in windows:  http://i.imgur.com/ZStyb6P.png?1

Comment: did you have any important files in that partition please backup before deleting.

Comment: see that image c: shows that it was a logical drive.

Comment: Bur it shows all other as primary. What I found was at max, only 4 partitions can be primary.

Comment: MBR disk supports only 4 primary partitions but GPT disk supports 128 primary partitions.

Comment: Run this command to check whether your disk is GPT or MBR `gdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: In step 5, won't sliding the bar to the leftmost bring the partition above the sda5 (/home)?

Comment: And make sure that there was no key symbol in all the `/dev/sda` partitions.

Comment: Yes. Here is the screenshot after deleting the partition sda8: http://i.imgur.com/2WAVPOE.png?1

Comment: is that it appears like my second screenshot?like unallocated space before that.

Comment: It shows free space preceding to be 100.1 GB. So I think that you were right and it will place the /root right under the /home. Still I'm waiting for assurance from you. :)

Comment: yes please try that.

Comment: It's still not allowing to create as primary partition (showing both primary and extended option as greyed out). Let me know what to do next. Here's the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/xWQjdLh.png?1

Comment: I will for sure (if it allows me to do so, since I have very less number of reps). You have been of great help. Thank You very much, now I'm going to shrink the extended partition and lets see what happens :)

Comment: "It is not possible to create more than 4 primary partitions" Can I somehow make the last one (sda4) logical (put that into the extended partition)?

Comment: did you have any files on sda4?I think it is not necessary.Delete it and create new primary partition from the unallocated space.

Comment: you can't upvote my answer but you can accept it by pressing tick mark below the down arrow.

Comment: They are provided by the manufacturer and I am afraid to delete them as they may have to be checked time to time.

Comment: Is there any chance if I install windows on the unallocated partition(if possible) and then using the softwares like AOMEI partition manager, convert the primary to logical? Then again using Gparted, delete the partition (in which windows will be installed) and make a new primary?

Comment: it only allocates 3.75 mb,mount that partition in ubuntu and copy the files from that.And then delete that.

Comment: I can't mount it, nothing happens on right clicking and hitting mount. I am using live cd (since I downloaded the 64bit ISO in Ubuntu only which I can no longer use as Windows overwrote the grub which inturn can't be repaired without 64 bit version).

Comment: try this on terminal to mount sda4. `sudo mount /dev/sda4`

Comment: I get error: "mount: can't find /dev/sda4/ in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
"

Comment: sorry try this, `sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media`

Comment: Now I can't even see that partition now in the explorer.

Comment: try this command `cd /media && ls` there you can find the sda4 partition.Or you can move to the media folder through nautilus,there you find the mounted partition.

Comment: The output of the command is '$RECYCLE.BIN' The prompt also got changed to /media adn when I tried ls, it again showed '$RECYCLE.BIN' I guess there is nothing in that drive :p

Comment: you don't worry plz delete that.What's you problem in deleting that? i will clear your doubt.

Comment: I deleted it and installed windows in it. But one thing I could not understand is it's showing two windows options while booting. I installed previous in that logical drive which has been deleted now. Why is it asking so then? I've tried repairing windows boot loader with thosr commands bootrec /fixmbr etc. But no gain.

Comment: Try boot-repair

Comment: It's not a question regarding the partition problem I was earlier having. Just asking: I clicked recommended repair then it asked if I wanted to install pastebin (something like that) I hit yes and now it's stuck at Enabling BootInfo (This may require several minutes). I've been waiting for about half an hour now. Any idea?

Comment: it connects to the internet and paste the bootrepair  log to pastebin.com and then it provides the pastebin url.just skip that if you r not having internet connected.

Comment: I do have internet (much slow though, 512 kbps) but when I tried it last time, it didn't take this long. Since I have started it already, either I have to wait for it to complete or have to kill it. :/

Comment: I killed it and can see grub but NO Windows loader option in it :(

Comment: I've tried recommended repair again but still no gain. Since the original purpose has been solved and this discussion has become too long, I'll make another thread for that. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Tarun Avinash, can you both take the important information and move it to the question/answer?

Comment: @Braiam I've added a summary and the title so that users may get to know what they'll find in the answer. But as the solution of the question of bringing a partition out of extended has been solved but the main purpose of the question, to dual-boot still persists, I've made a new question. I'll appreciate if you could tell me what I should do if I don't get answers (or help me).

Comment: @Tarun ask another question with gparted screenshot.I will help you.

Comment: @AvinashRaj http://askubuntu.com/questions/389115/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows8-grub-doesnt-detect-windows-boot-repair-di/389119#389119

Answer (score 0):

open grub file under `/etc/defaults/grub`

check for your windows partition information .

finally don't forget to update grub by

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot your machine. It should work.

Comment: There is no info regarding windows and maybe that's why it doesn't show the Windows in the grub menu.

Here is the grub file: http://pastebin.com/kZcQAT9f