# Resize partitions in Gparted

Tags: gparted, partitioning

I'm running Linux and Windows XP on the same HDD and my Linux partition is very small.

What I want to do is take about 10GB from any of the other partitions and add it to the Linux one. My hard drive is currently a big mess but you can have a look at what it looks like in GParted here [image: gparted]

I've tried following online tutorials but they all assume that the partitions that you are resizing are next to one another but this is not the case and I have no idea what I'm supposed to be doing.

I'm not really fussed where I take the 10gb from, but I would ideally like to do it from `sda6` since it has a bit more than any of the other drives.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: see this also for moving the unallocated space  http://askubuntu.com/a/389067/202806

Answer (score 1):

You can only add space to a partition if the free space is adjacent to the partition you wish to add it to.

You will have to do this in several steps from a live USB.

make sda6 smaller by  10 Gb -> apply changes

move sda5 -> apply changes

delete (or move) swap -> apply changes

add 10 Gb to your root partition -> apply changes.

I advise you clean up / re-order you hard drive numbers as labels sucs as "sda6" are meaningless, the free space has to be physically adjacent to your partition.

Se re-order, from a live usb, run

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

Then at the fdisk prompt

- press “x” to enter Expert Mode
- press “f” to fix the drive order
- press “i” to ignore the warning (if it shows)
- press “w” to write changes to the disk
- press “q” to  quit fdisk

See http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk or the built in help "h" for further information.

Then reboot and run gparted, in steps.

Comment: if smaller sda6,creates an unallocated space of 10 gb below the /sda6,so to move the unallocated space upwards he had to right-click on sda6 and the move the slider to extreme right.

Comment: What will happen if I delete swap?

Comment: you don't need to delete the swap,just move the unallocated space upwards,see this,it would help you in moving partitions http://askubuntu.com/a/387176/202806