# How to merge two unallocated partitions using GParted?

Tags: installation, partitioning, gparted

I am having trouble merging two unallocated partitions (free spaces) using GParted. I need to merge them into one single partition which I can then break into "root" and "home" for my pending Ubuntu installation. Please help!

Here is a snapshot of what my partition table looks like right now:
(There are two unallocated partitions of 36.23 GB and 11.16GB respectively, which I need to merge)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move /dev/sda6 to the right -> apply changes

the free space will now all be adjacent, make a partition in the free space.

If you wish, you can then re-number your partitions, see [Resize partitions in Gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392632/resize-partitions-in-gparted/392638#392638)

Comment: You may have to resize and downsize it then, in 2 steps - make larger -> apply changes -> make smaller, free space at beginning of partition -> apply changes

Comment: Gparted will do that for you for supported file systems because it (usually) speeds up the movement of the partition.