# GRUB not booting correctly after dual boot install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi, boot-repair

I followed these instructions to dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu:

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported?rq=1)

I was successfully able to install ubuntu. But then I couldn't boot into windows 8

```
  "File: \Boot\BCD Status: 0xc000000c Info: the boot configuration data for your pc is missing or contains errors."
```

So I ran boot-repair in ubuntu.

But then when I restarted computer I get:

```
error: invalid arch independent ELF magic
grub rescue >
```

At the end of boot-repair I had this message:

```
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!
```

I have no idea how to do that. I am able to boot into ubuntu by hitting the F12 on startup, otherwise it goes to the screen with the invalid arch error.

Here is the summary of the boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6535680

EDIT: Still not able to boot into windows 8 from grub screen btw I get:

```
error: unknown command 'drivemap'.
error: invalid  EFI file path.
```

EDIT: A few more details: when I installed ubuntu I had my BIOS set to legacy mode (not UEFI) as suggested by the article above. When I installed Ubuntu I chose the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8" option.

Comment: Did you able to boot ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my post, I can get into ubuntu by going into the boot menu on startup

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/381601/windows-doesnt-boot-after-updating-to-13-10/381603#381603 try this.

Comment: Without windows disk,it's not possible.

Comment: From the boot-repair output, it seems as if it has concluded normally. The message was telling you that if you aren't taken straight into GRUB, you should open BIOS on startup and manually set it to boot from sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi. Inability to load Win 8 looks like a separate problem.

Comment: @Pavel can you describe how to set it to boot from sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi I don't believe  that is an option

Comment: From your boot-repair, it appears you have two hard drives: 24GB (sda) and 1000GB (sdb). You need to set the 1000GB drive as the highest-priority boot device in BIOS Setup (in the boot options section).

Comment: So i was able to fix windows boot but only if I boot from boot menu  (f12) into windows. If i boot into grub and then choose to boot into windows from grub I still get error. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm confused. When you boot and DO NOTHING, does GRUB load? If it doesn't my previous comment was abt fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say in one of your comments that you can boot to Windows by selecting its boot entry in the firmware's boot manager, my recommendation is to try [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You can do this risk-free by using the CD-R or USB flash drive image; prepare the medium and try it. If you can boot to both Linux and Windows, you can then install the Debian-package version under Ubuntu. rEFInd will then take over from GRUB as your primary boot manager. You may need to clean up unwanted boot options by deleting files from the `/boot/efi/EFI` directory tree in Linux or by using the `dont_scan_dirs` or `dont_scan_files` options in `refind.conf`; see the rEFInd documentation for details.