# can't boot windows 8.1 after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6901378/

here is how my boot looks like can someone help me please

I have tried boot repair auto repair but it didn't fix the issue.
I'm kinda of a windows guy and don't have that much of knowledge in linux zone

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sda2` ntfs partition.So you have to repair your windows boot files and then run boot-repair.

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/381603/202806) solution for repairing your windows boot files and  reinstall grub2.