# Windows crashed and i cant boot into windows recovery disk or installer. pc boots into ubuntu. i can access windows partition from ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I am dual booting Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7. Somehow, a file system on windows is corrupt. I can still see windows files from Ubuntu as its working properly. I tried using windows recovery discs and booting from different windows installers as well but when ever the boot is about to start, Ubuntu is loaded.

Whenever I try opening the

```
windows 7 (loader)
```

on grub thing, i get the message

```
BOOTMGR is corrupt. cannot boot
```

.. what can I do?

Comment: You need to repair your windows bootloader.Follow the steps given in [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/381603/202806)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild your Boot configuration data(BCD).

## Pay Attention! if you do this grub will be deleted and you can not reach ubuntu anymore.

When you decide what you wanna do;

**Boot your pc with Windows Install disc or usb**

**Hit the 'Repair Computer'**

**System Recovery Window will appear**

**Select your os then click next**

**Select Command prompt then type the codes below**

```
BootRec.exe /fixmbr
chkdsk /r
BootRec.exe /FixBoot
BootRec.exe /ScanOs
BootRec.exe /RebuildBcd
```