# I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 along side windows 8 and can no longer boot into Windows

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 along side windows 8 and can no longer boot into Windows. GRUB shows Windows 8 as an option but when I select it I see the Windows logo for a minute and then the screen goes black. 
I did not have this problem after the initial install, it began 2 days later.

Answer (score 1):

boot into your ubuntu if you can or run ubuntu from pendrive and install grub repair

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

and read these[instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on recommended methods

Comment: I ran boot repair and the problem has not changed. Here is the URL from my boot repair readout;   http://paste.ubuntu.com/6937794/

Comment: when you run a **sudo update-grub** does it detect Windows?

Comment: Yes it does detect windows.

Comment: Option two is to make a bootable flash disk with Ubuntu and reinstall ubuntu to restore it back. That should not affect your windows and it will appear back on the grub.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change UEFI mode in bios to legacy mode.After that save the changes and then exit.

Now select the windows option from grub.It works.

Comment: I do not believe I have UEFI. When I enter BIOS I do not see a UEFI mode. I do note that I have BIOS version 1.51

Comment: try to repair your windows boot files and then try boot-repair.See http://askubuntu.com/a/381603/202806

Comment: I do not have a windows install disk. Is there a way for me to create one? I have a product key for Win8, keep in mind that I will be using Ubuntu 12.04 when creating it.